# Command line to get all users from an AD group

Tags: windows-server-2003, command-line-interface, active-directory

with the following setup, I try to get all users in the `de` group.

```
- domain.local (domain)
 - users_and_groups (ou)
  - orga (ou)
   - groups (ou)
    - de (group)
```

I tried the following commands

```
dsget group "CN=de,DC=domain,DC=local" -members
dsget group "CN=de,OU=users_and_groups,DC=domain,DC=local" -members
dsget group "CN=de,OU=users_and_groups,OU=orga,DC=domain,DC=local" -members
dsget group "CN=de,OU=users_and_groups,OU=orga,OU=groups,DC=domain,DC=domain,DC=local" -members
```

But all fail with `Directory object not found`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 3rd command is almost correct, but you have the OU parts the wrong way round in your command - you need to specify them in order as if you are moving up through the hierarchy. Try this instead:

```
dsget group "CN=de,OU=groups,OU=orga,OU=users_and_groups,DC=domain,DC=local" -members
```